# Delete a reference with a composite key in OData Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an OData Web API with a bunch of different objects and navigation properties.  From what I understand, the proper way to remove the relationship between two objects is by using the following call.  This will remove item 456 from shopping cart 123:

```
DELETE: http://localhost:61506/odata/shoppingCarts(123)/items/$ref?$id=456
```

This is also an acceptable way:

```
DELETE: http://localhost:61506/odata/shoppingCarts(123)/items/$ref?$id=http://localhost:61506/odata/items(456)
```

The method looks like this and works fine:

```
public IHttpActionResult DeleteRef([FromODataUri] int key, string navigationProperty, [FromODataUri] string relatedKey)
{
   ...
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how will this call look like if the "item" object has a composite key?

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

I could call the following to get an item with the composite key:

```
http://localhost:61506/odata/items(id='123',source='abc')
```

I'm assuming the following should work but I can't get the routing to work:

```
 DELETE: http://localhost:61506/odata/shoppingCarts(123)/items/$ref?$id=http://localhost:61506/odata/items(id='123',source='abc')
```

I'm also not sure how the first delete reference call should look.  I've tried a few of these:

```
DELETE: http://localhost:61506/odata/shoppingCarts(123)/items/$ref?$id=123&$source=abc
DELETE: http://localhost:61506/odata/shoppingCarts(123)/items/$ref?$id=(id='123',source='abc')
```

I'm missing something somewhere, I'm just not sure how the call should look and the routing and method should accept the incoming request.

Comment: The key in this case indicates the column is shared with another table(s) in the database and the values are unique in each column.  Since they are unique you only need one key to perform a lookup.

Comment: It's a composite key.  Both of those columns are in the same table and both together make up the unique key.  You could have a row with id = 1 and source = abc and the next row could be id = 1 and source = def.

Comment: Can you have all four  in table 1) Id= 123, Source = ABC 2) Id= 123, Source = DEF 3) Id= 456, Source = ABC 4) Id= 456, Source = DEF.  The answer is no.  You can only have 1 & 4 because either ID is duplicated or Source is duplicated. in the other two cases.

Comment: This is getting a bit off topic here but yes, you can have all four.  This site gives a good definition: "A composite key is a combination of two or more columns in a table that can be used to uniquely identify each row in the table when the columns are combined uniqueness is guaranteed, but when it taken individually it does not guarantee uniqueness." (https://www.javatpoint.com/sql-composite-key).  Anyways, because of the two keys, I need a way to call this delete ref by including both keys.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN